# Plotting data from a netCDF in ggplot for R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, mapping, netcdf

I'm looking to plot data from a netCDF from the following source:

http://fizz.phys.dal.ca/~atmos/martin/?page_id=140

Just some simple, but large, files with PM 2.5 concentrations, latitudes, and longitudes.

I'm looking to plot this data on a map of Massachusetts.

Currently, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (286): x
```

And the following is my code:

```
library(chron)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(lattice)
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
memory.limit(size=56000)
getwd()
wd <- "C:/Users/tadams15/Desktop/Practicum/vd"
setwd(wd)
file <- "1adjust.nc"
ncin <- nc_open(file)
print(ncin) # Displays plenty of information about netCDF
lat <-ncvar_get(ncin,"LAT")
lon <-ncvar_get(ncin,"LON")
pm <- ncvar_get(ncin,"PM25")
states <- map_data("state")
Mass <- subset(states,region == 'massachusetts')
ggplot(data = Mass)
image(pm)
lat.df <- data.frame(lat)
lon.df <- data.frame(lon)
pm.df<- data.frame(pm)


m <- map_data('state',region='Massachusetts')

graph <-ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon( data=m, aes(x=lon, y=lat,group=group),colour="black", fill="white" )+
  geom_point(data=pm,aes(x=lon,y=lat),,colour="red",)+
  ggtitle("Distribution of Flash Flood Events in CONUS")+
  xlab('Longitude')+
  ylab('Latitude')+
  coord_fixed()

print(graph)
```

I was wondering if anyone was comfortable with the ggplot function and whether or not any help could be offered. I'm very new to R and even newer to managing netCDF file types. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try  `pm.df = data.frame(lat, lon,pm)` and then `geom_point(data=pm.df, aes(lon, lat))`

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I'll reproduce my data shortly and post it here! @Tung